# Когда остановится такой цикл? В си

Tags: c, циклы, double, числа-с-плавающей-точкой

```
double x=1.0;
do
{
x/=2.0;
}
while( 1.0+x>1.0 );
}
```

Comment: Что собственно мешало взять да проверить? Только не забыть подсчитать циклы. Очень полезно проверять самостоятельно всякие идеи

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Через 53 итерации этот цикл остановится. Вещественные числа двойной точности поддерживают только 53 бита мантиссы. Из-за этого сумма `1 + 2^-53` не может быть представлена точно и округляется к единице. Условие оказывается ложным и цикл завершается.

Вот ваш код дополненный печатью:

```
// gcc -std=c11 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Werror loop_stop.c -lm

#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    double x = 1.0;
    do {
        x /= 2.0;
        printf("1 + 2^%.0lf > 1 - %s\n", log2(x), (1.0 + x > 1.0) ? "yes" : "no");
    } while (1.0 + x > 1.0);
}
```

> ```
> $ gcc -std=c11 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Werror loop_stop.c -lm && ./a.out 
> 1 + 2^-1 > 1 - yes
> 1 + 2^-2 > 1 - yes
> ...
> 1 + 2^-51 > 1 - yes
> 1 + 2^-52 > 1 - yes
> 1 + 2^-53 > 1 - no
> ```

Comment: Depends on... Например, в VС++ включаем `/fp:strict` и получаем ваш результат; ставим `/fp:fast` - и уже при 1075 итерациях...